# How to modify prometheus exposed metric names using Actuator in Spring-boot 2

Tags: spring-boot, prometheus, spring-boot-actuator

I am using Actuator in springboot 2 to expose /actuator/prometheus endpoint from which a prometheus instance will pull metrics.

Everithing works perfect except because I am in need of tweak the metric names. I mean not the suffix (_count, _total, _bucket, ...) which are meaningful for Prometheus but something like:

> http_server_requests_seconds_count -> http_server_requests_count
>   http_server_requests_seconds_max -> latency_seconds_max
>   http_server_requests_seconds_sum -> latency_seconds_sum
>   http_server_requests_seconds_bucket -> latency_seconds_bucket

Is there any better approach to this?

P.S.

I know i can use

```
management.metrics.web.server.requests-metric-name=different
```

to get

```
different_seconds_count
different_seconds_max 
different_seconds_sum 
different_seconds_bucket
```

but it would be difficult to:

1º remove the _seconds suffix

2º use a different base name for only one of them

I am guessing i could write an alternative `PrometheusRenameFilter` but not sure how to configure it to the default registry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now I know how I can customize the global registry:

e.g. to set a custom meter filter:

```
@Configuration
public class MetricsConfig {
    @Bean
    MeterRegistryCustomizer<MeterRegistry> metricsConfig() {
        return registry -> registry.config().meterFilter(new CustomRenameFilter());
    }
}
```

However, setting a custom rename filter in the registry only allow to rename the base metric name. 
It does not act on the suffixes nor allow to act on specific metric belonging a set e.g. generated by the summary.

with a custom `NamingConvention` I can add suffixes to convention base name ... I could even alter existing suffixes or replace convention base name.

Finally please note that Histogram prometheus metric type expects the creation of

```
<basename>_bucket
<basename>_sum
<basename>_count
```

with those specific names so it might be incorrect to tweak the component in the way I want because that would be a diferent component.

Answer (score 3):

you can override this method and update the naming convention:

```
@Configuration
public class MetricsConfiga {
@Bean
MeterRegistryCustomizer<MeterRegistry> configurer(String applicationName) {
    return (registry) -> registry.config().namingConvention(new NamingConvention() {
        @Override
        public String name(String name, Meter.Type type, String baseUnit) {
            return "PREFIX" + Arrays.stream(name1.split("\\."))
                .filter(Objects::nonNull)
                .collect(Collectors.joining("_"));
        }
       });
    }
}
```